# popViewController works on one view, not another

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a couple of UIViewControllers and related nib files. I can call either of them from another UIView controller ("StartController") by pressing a button for each one. Each of the called UIViewControllers had a button which I've connected up to a related method which pops the view off the stack, like so:

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

The methods for both are coded in the their respective implementation classes, like this:

```
    - (IBAction) validateEntries{

            // some validation goes here        

            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and this:

```
-(IBAction) returnToStart {

    NSLog(@"returnToStart method called");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

They both have the methods declared in their respective interface files:

```
-(IBAction) returnToStart;
```

and

```
-(IBAction)validateEntries;
```

And the buttons in the nibs are connected to these respectively via the "touch up inside" event. The first one works fine, but the second doesn't - it doesn't even call the method. I don't get what could be causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like you dont actually have the button hooked up to the right method inside IB if the method isnt ever being called

Comment: Close enough. I had connected it to the wrong event on the button - I was falling asleep at my keyboard. If you want to make an answer out of it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you dont actually have the button hooked up to the right method inside IB if the method isnt ever being called